# Magento 2: ScopeConfig Error when I use it on \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post class

Tags: php, magento2

First of all I was extending the module for contact us and I wanted to check on backend if its enabled or not using `ScopeConfig` but I've encountered this problem. I already tried deleting the generated files and run setup upgrade command.

On my assumption I think I am lacking something on my codes

CODE:

```
<?php
namespace SCI\Form\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;

    }

    public function ifEnabled(){
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('extended_contact/config/extended_contact_enabled',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        die($this->ifEnabled());

        return parent::execute();

    }
}
```

Note: Its working when I changed the class form \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post to \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

ERROR:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::__construct() must implement
>   interface Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface, array given, called
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\training\app\code\SCI\Form\Controller\Index\Post.php
>   on line 17 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\training\vendor\magento\module-contact\Controller\Index\Post.php:49
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\training\app\code\SCI\Form\Controller\Index\Post.php(17):
>   Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context),
>   Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\training\generated\code\SCI\Form\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor.php(14):
>   SCI\Form\Controller\Index\Post->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config), Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\training\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   SCI\Form\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Conte
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\training\vendor\magento\module-contact\Controller\Index\Post.php
>   on line 49

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change your function to below code for fix error.

```
public function ifEnabled(){
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'extended_contact/config/extended_contact_enabled',
        $storeScope
    );
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that and its not working, its displaying the same error